# "duplicating" an Image inside a picturebox

Tags: c#

I have two pictureboxes pb1 and pb2. I want to specify the image inside pb1 to the image in pb2

```
pb1.image = pb2.image;
```

does not work. Any other tips? I can't specify the path of the picture, as it may change, so the path needs to change as well.

Comment: `pb1.Image = pb2.Image.Clone()`

Comment: _does not work_  This is not a helpful problem description!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I just tried to use `pb1.Image = pb2.Image;` and it worked for me. If you are asking how to have two PictureBoxes in sync with each other, so that changing the image in one updates the other automatically, I don't believe this is possible.

If this is the case, you would likely need to just do something like this each time the image needs to change:

```
pb1.Image = pb2.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\path\to\file.jpg");
```

---

**Original answer:**

The [`System.Drawing.Image.Clone()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.clone?view=netframework-4.7.2) method "creates an exact copy of this Image."

Use `pb1.Image = (Image)pb2.Image.Clone();`

The cast is necessary because the method returns the image cast as an `object`.